# Cisco IOS: How to clear terminal?

Tags: cisco-router

In a Cisco IOS terminal session I'd like to be able to clear the screen similar to the `clear` command or the `ctrl-L` key combination on a Linux/UNIX box.
Most sources suggest to reside to terminal emulator features for that functionality, but that is not appealing to me.
One [forum conversation](https://community.cisco.com/t5/network-management/tcl-clear-screen/td-p/733898) suggests to use a tcl shell to emit an escape sequence like so:

```
proc clear_term { } {
    exec "terminal international"
    puts "\x1B\x5B\x32\x4A\x1B\x5B\x30\x3B\x30\x48"
}
```

I gave that a try. The escape sequence works as expected if the terminal session was in international mode already when the tcl script is run, although obviously the script tries to take care of that temporarily itself.

Did IOS behavior change in recent years in this regard? The linked forum conversation is from 2007, I am trying this on IOS 15 though.
Is there something I can do get this to work regardless of the terminal state (international or not)?